# NoMethodError: undefined method `validate_integrity' for :LogoUploader:Symbol carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

i am using carrierwave with rails 5. I have created uploader for my logo image. And mounted it in my event model like

```
mount_uploader :logo, :LogoUploader
```

But i am getting error

> NoMethodError: undefined method `validate_integrity' for :LogoUploader:Symbol

Can anone help me to resolve this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mount_uploader` expects a class name when you are passing it a symbol.

```
mount_uploader :logo, LogoUploader
```

Comment: ah my bad, That was a stupid mistake. It worked thanks buddy.